# Throw bad_cast when converting pointers with dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reference

dynamic_cast throws `bad_cast` exception if you cast a reference but as I know in the standard pointers are considered as references, i.e. a pointer is a type of a reference.
So should I get bad_cast when casting pointers?

This question arose from the try-catch block from [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/). Is this try-catch block inappropriate?

Comment: where did you find that "a pointer is a type of a reference."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No with pointers in case of a bad cast, `dynamic_cast` will return a `null`.
Also, dynamic_cast works only on Polymorphic classes, So if you are talking about built in data types(from the link in your question) then `static_cast` is what you should be using.

And btw, References are **NOT** pointers.

Comment: I don't say references are pointer, I say pointers are a type of a reference. That are really different thigs!

Comment: No pointers are **not** a type of Reference, They are both different **things**

Comment: @Narek: in C++ terminology, "reference" is used for, well, references. I agree that it's a VERY awkward terminology. But to avoid misunderstandings, we need to very carefully keep tongue straight (or whatever the idiomatic expression is in English!). :-)

Comment: If it does not throw during pointer conversion then why there is a try-cats block in the link? Is it inappropriate?

Comment: @Narek: If you notice, the code in the link checks for null after every `dynamic_cast`. The `try-catch` there would catch the `bad_alloc` exception thrown from `new` but that `try-catch` is ill placed to do even that. So Yes that is an bad example.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the original question "So should I get bad_cast when casting pointers?", No.

That's why you can see constructions like

```
if( T* pT = dynamic_cast<T*>( p ) ) ...  // use pT in if body
```

Regarding the new question "Is this try-catch block inappropriate?", no, it is a `try`-`catch` block to catch allocation errors; it's not related to the `dynamic_cast` as such.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Since `dynamic_cast<T*>` does not throw exceptions, one of the try-catch blocks are completely unnecessary.

However you can easily define your own cast function that does indeed throw exception for pointers. That is what I am doing in my own code (simplified code, and mind you I use garbage collection so I can throw pointers without consequence):

```
template <class Class, class Object>
inline Class* cast (Object* obj)
{
    Class* result = dynamic_cast<Class*>(obj);
    if( obj != null and result == null ){
        throw new ClassCastException(); //  unusual, throw bad_cast if you prefer
    }
    return result;
}

template <class Class, class Object>
inline const Class* cast (const Object* obj)
{
    const Class* result = dynamic_cast<const Class*>(obj);
    if( obj != null and result == null ){
        throw new ClassCastException(); //  unusual, throw bad_cast if you prefer
    }
    return result;
}
```

On a side note, I also use it as a syntactic sugar for static_cast, but this is only possible because I do not use it to dynamic_cast references and const references:

```
template <class Class, class Object>
inline Class cast (const Object& obj)
{
    return static_cast<Class>(obj);
}
```

I'd say you are better off implementing your own casting function that is coherent in terms of exception handling and do precisely what you want and expect. I did and never looked back.

Comment: Nice but I must say completely out of context. The problem is with OP's understanding of `dynamic_cast` throwing an exception or not , and S/He cites a particular example to clear that understanding, OP doesn't want this behavior.